# Rabbitmq loses persistent messages after killing nodes

Tags: linux, docker

I've created a durable queue (on 2 nodes mirrored, ha-mode: automatic). I've put messages in it with the delivery mode = 2. 
- On the UI I can see that the queue is durable (D) and the messages are in the queue and they are persistent. 
- The mnesia location is attached as a volume. 
- I can see that the 0.rdq file is not null.

Presumable, that the messages were saved to the disk.

After that I docker killed both nodes. When I started the nodes again, all the messages were disappeared.

Is there any other settings not to lose messages after this disaster simulation?

Rabbitmq version: 3.7.8

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution:
Gotta create the advanced.config file and set the queue_index_max_journal_entries to the needs.